# Get Updating Value of Column in Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, triggers, sql-update

```
DECLARE @IsDeleted AS BIT = 0;

    SELECT @IsDeleted = IsDeleted from Updated

    IF @IsDeleted=1 
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Reviews
    SET IsDeleted = @IsDeleted
    WHERE CompanyID = 1
END;
```

I want to update `Reviews` if the `Company` `IsDeleted` column is updated to 1.
How to determine is updating value is '**1**'

It's error `SELECT @IsDeleted = IsDeleted from Updated`

Answer (score 4):

The pseudoatables available in a trigger are inserted or deleted, there is no updated table.

Since you stated t-sql, you should understand that in SQL server triggers operate on batches not single rows. This trigger needs to be completely rewriten to handle multiple record updates. Do not set anything to the value of a scalar variable in a trigger from the inserted or deleted tables.  JOin to them instead (and of course when you are updating, don't ever write an update statement without excluding any records where the current value matches the new value. Silly to update a million records when only 2 have changed. Performance is critical ina trigger, so it is even more important there not to update things that don't need updating.